# bind values from xml to linq in C#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have an xml file containing values for thousand of videos in following format

```
 <Album Id="123" name="ABC100">
        <URL>https://vimeo.com/album/123456</URL>
        <Videos>
          <Name>Video 1</Name>
          <URL>https://vimeo.com/1234561</URL>
          <Name>Video 2</Name>
          <URL>https://vimeo.com/1234562</URL>
          <Name>Video 3</Name>
          <URL>https://vimeo.com/1234563</URL>
          <Name>Video 4</Name>
          <URL>https://vimeo.com/1234564</URL> 
          <Name>Video 5</Name>
          <URL>https://vimeo.com/1234565</URL>
          <Name>Video 6</Name>
          <URL>https://vimeo.com/1234566</URL>

</videos>
</Album>
```

I have to search album via it's name attribute and get all values of Name and URL from it's decedents . I need to use linq query in C# and bind values to grid view. I am using following code

```
var result = doc.Root.Descendants("Album").Where(vm => (string)vm.Attribute("name") == txtBoxSearch.Text.Trim())
                .Descendants("Videos")
                .Select(vmClient => vmClient.Nodes());
```

I have trouble to get values from nodes, returned in variable result, in such a way that all url values from videos node should b displayed in gridview.

Thanks

Comment: does result contain all the URLs ?

Comment: I have used SelectMany instead of Select and got the result as following System.Xml.Linq.Extensions+d__29`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement] System.Xml.Linq.Extensions+d__29`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement] System.Xml.Linq.Extensions+d__29`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]  Value is printed three times in gridview